# Issues in starting windows service with wix

Tags: windows, service, wix

I have a service which needs to be installed and started with wix(Windows xml Installer).

I have made small windows service just for test purpose.
But not able to install and start with wix setup project.

Following is the code for the setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="WindoServiceSetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="26b8eb77-ad9e-4661-9559-3480f3e21434">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WindoServiceSetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WindoServiceSetup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="FileInstalled" Guid="9FED4055-8C10-49CA-A96D-532C44AAD415">
        <File Id="In" Name="WinService" Source="E:\WinService\WinService\WinService\bin\Debug\WinService.exe" KeyPath="yes"></File>
      </Component>
        <Component Id="FileInstalled4" Guid="3890C9A0-C5AA-49B7-AC78-60065CD2390E">
        <File Id="In1" Name="WinService1" Source="E:\WinService\WinService\WinService\bin\Debug\WinService.pdb" KeyPath="yes"></File>
        </Component>
      <Component Id="FileInstalled1" Guid="57A5E2AC-B050-4830-9FBD-180D3B2B1529">
        <File Id="In2" Name="WinService2" Source="E:\WinService\WinService\WinService\bin\Debug\WinService.InstallLog" KeyPath="yes"></File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="FileInstalled2" Guid="1866F830-C90B-4733-B987-437AF376D9FA">
      <File Id="In3" Name="WinService4" Source="E:\WinService\WinService\WinService\bin\Debug\WinService.exe.config" KeyPath="yes"></File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="FileInstalled3" Guid="5306EDB1-7FD5-4070-9C98-FB38CCEB68EC">
        <File Id="In4" Name="WinService3" Source="E:\WinService\WinService\WinService\bin\Debug\InstallUtil.InstallLog" KeyPath="yes"></File>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="SeviceSetup" Guid="672FD8AD-7BD9-4924-9059-7FC7042DC718" KeyPath="yes">
        <ServiceInstall Id="Installs"  Name="WinService.exe" Start="auto"  ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no" DisplayName="Testservice" Type ="ownProcess" Account="LocalSystem">
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="InsatllControl" Name="ServiceCnt" Start="both" Wait="no">
        </ServiceControl>
        <ServiceControl Id="InstallCntrolstop" Name="Servicercnt1" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no">
        </ServiceControl>
      </Component>
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and the windows service code

```
class WinService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
    {
        // The main entry point for the process
        static void Main()
        {
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun =
              new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new WinService() };
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "WinService";
        }
        private string folderPath = @"D:\sam";
        /// <summary>
        /// Set things in motion so your service can do its work.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\WindowsService.txt",
                                FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" WindowsService: Service Started at " +
               DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " +
               DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\n");
            m_streamWriter.Flush();
            m_streamWriter.Close();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Stop this service.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath +
              "\\WindowsService.txt",
              FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" WindowsService: Service Stopped at " +
              DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " +
              DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\n");
            m_streamWriter.Flush();
            m_streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Issue
**Verify that you have specify privilege fro running system services.**

As i have been exporing this,people say that this message is common for all issues
I have admin rights and also added all the dependacy files still no luck...
any help..

Comment: You should report the error number because that message is generic to a number of service install issues. It may be 1920, meaning the service was installed and failed to start, but maybe 1923 meaning it couldn't be installed. If your service code fails on startup you'll see 1920, so you'll need some debugging code, and check that any dependences are installed.

Comment: there is no error code as such it only shows that
" Verify that you have specify privilege fro running system services"

Comment: Do the install taking a log by adding /L*v <path to text log file> to an msiexec command line to install your MSI and see where and what the error is. I suspect your service is just failing to start and crashing. There's no try/catch and no checking in that code that anything actually works. Write an event log entry as soon as the process starts to verify that it can start and there's no missing dependency. Write another debug event log entry at the end of your OnStart method. If you don't see that then you're crashing in OnStart. If the service fails to complete start you'll see that error.

Comment: thanks I will do above concern and will come back to it

Answer (score 0):

Your name definition is wrong inside the ServiceInstall tag. There you have to specify the name of the service and not the path to the executable. And then you missed the File definition before the ServiceInstall tag, where you can specify the path to the service executable. In my experience it is also better to use a seperate ComponentGroup for the ServiceInstall. Here is a working example:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="CG_ServiceInstaller" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Guid="F7E041AB-3227-4272-92C1-4A12685F30AF" >
        <File Source="$(var.YourService.TargetDir)YourService.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                          Type="ownProcess"
                          Name="Your Service Name"
                          DisplayName="TCP Json Service"
                          Description="TCP Server on port 1234"
                          Start="auto"
                          ErrorControl="normal"
                          Account="LocalSystem"/>
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="YourService" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```